# Replace Formulas in a range based on Value

Tags: excel, vba, case

I'm trying to find a faster way to look in a range, and replace the formula with the cell's value but only for the cells that show a value other than 'Not Here'. My code so far is below. It works, but it works slowly! Despite an extensive search, I haven't yet come up with a better method.

```vb
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng2 = Sheets("User Daily").Range("I2:I" & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Punch Times").Range("G:G")))

For Each Row In rng2.Rows
    For Each Cell In Row.Cells
        Select Case Cell.Value
        Case "Not Here"
            'do nothing
        Case Else
            Cell.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                   :=False, Transpose:=False
        End Select
    Next Cell
Next Row
```

Comment: You could use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`.

Comment: For the `Case Else`, the following 3 lines can be simplified to `Cell.Value = Cell.Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting my comments into an answer:

> You could use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`

> For the `Case Else`, the following 3 lines can be simplified to `Cell.Value = Cell.Value`.

You could replace everything after the `Set rng2 = ...` line with the following:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim formulaCells As Range
Set formulaCells = rng2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
On Error GoTo 0

If formulaCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<~ no cells with formulas

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In formulaCells
    If cell.Value <> "Not Here" Then
        cell.Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next
```